# WPF - Styles declared in Resource Dictionary not getting applied

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, resourcedictionary, app.xaml

I have added the following styles in App.xml file of WPF application under Application.Resources tag and these styles are getting applied to the controls.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="fontStyling">
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource fontStyling}" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource fontStyling}" />
```

Now, i have created a "Resource Dictionary" file, moved the above styles to Resource dictionary file and accessed the "Resource Dictionary" file in the App.XAML file using merged dictionaries

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="GlobalSettingsDictionary">
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/GlobalSettings.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

When i run the WPF application then the Styles in the resource dictionary are not getting applied to the controls present in the Main Window. When i use the same styles in App.xaml file then they are getting applied

Am i missing anything? Can you please suggest on what needs to be done to get the styles defined in the Resource dictionary are applied to the controls in the MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: Have you tried referencing the resource file in the `MainWindow.xaml`?  You may be able to sort out wiring issues there.  Is the `ResourceDictionary` defined in another project's namespace?

Comment: No, ResourceDictionary is not defined in another project's namespace.. i didnt try referencing the resource file in the MainWindow.xaml file. I am not sure how to reference the resource file but when i set a key name  to the styles defined in resource dictionary and provide that keys to a control then the styles are getting applied. Is this the correct process of setting styles defined in a resource dictionary using keys?